# Извлечение числа из строки регулярным выражением

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте уважаемые!

Вопрос по регулярным выражениям. Есть строка:

```
<link rel="search" title="Яндекс" 500)}};(function() { var title = " — Яндекс: нашлось 223 ответа"
```

Нужно вытащить от туда значение "223", которое заранее не известно.

`([0-9]*)` - Так не выйдет, выше этой строки есть ещё много кода, спец символов и других символов.

Пробую так: `([^A-Za-zА-Яа-я]*)([0-9]*)` - но грабятся все спец символы и другие цифры.

Пытался сделать "Яндекс:" якорем, так как подходит, по коду не встречается, но парсится только он.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(?:нашлось\s+)(.*?)(?=\s+ответ)
```

Протестировал на [примере](http://www.pcre.ru/eval/(%3F%3A%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8C%5Cs%2B)(.*%3F)(%3F%3D%5Cs%2B%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82)%40%3D%23%3D%40101%40%3D%23%3D%40%D0%AF%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%3A%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8C%203237%20%D0%BC%D0%BB%D0%BD%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2/): Яндекс: нашлось 3237 млн ответов

Поэтому (\d+) не катит

Comment: Вы решаете задачу за OP'а, а не отвечаете на вопрос, где не содержится упоминание варианта с "млн".

Comment: Разве тяжело вспомнить что ответ содержит в себе текстовые строки?Мне не сложно :)

Answer (score 3):

Как-то так:

```
'|(?<=нашлось\s).*?(?=\sответа)|m'
```

Comment: Так не катит
     Проверял в TestRExp

Answer (score 2):

```
/Яндекс: нашлось (\d+) ответ/
```

В слове «ответа» убрал последнюю букву, т.к. Яндексы, вероятно, окончания меняют, в зависимости от числа.

Если пишете на php, и разбираете лог с множеством однотипных строк, похожих на эту, можно попробовать более лёгкий и быстрый способ, чем регулярные выражения: ф-ю [`sscanf()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sscanf.php)

Answer (score 2):

Если в выдаче будут строчные коэффициенты, то совсем не нужно под каждый коэффициент писать свое регулярное выражение:

```
$re= "/Яндекс: нашлось (\\d+) (тыс|млн|млрд).*?ответов/";
$koef=Array("тыс"=>1000, "млн"=>1000000, "млрд"=>1000000000);
preg_match($re, $text, $res);
$questions=$res[1];
if ($res[2]) $questions*=$koef[$res[2]];
```